# How to reset f7SmartSelect values after clicking on an actionButton in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to set the selected values of the `f7SmartSelect` from the package `shinyMobile` to NULL (aka no values selected) after user clicks on an actionButton.

I have found a few solutions on this, but they all adress `selectizeInput` and unfortunately I cant figure out how to properly implement those `javascript`- Functions(?) for SmartSelect.

So here is a **MRE**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)

shinyApp(
  ui = f7Page(
    f7SingleLayout(
      navbar = f7Navbar(title = " "),
      f7Button("resetSmartSelect", "Reset Smart Select"),
      f7SmartSelect(
        inputId = "smartId",
        multiple = TRUE,
        label = "Choose a variable:",
        choices = colnames(mtcars)[-1],
        openIn = "popup"
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$resetSmartSelect, {
      #code to reset the values of 'smartId' aka the smartSelect and also uncheck the boxes
      #I have tried shinyjs::reset('smartId'), but it did nothing
    })
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I found the following javascript parts which should somehow solve my problem, but I cant figoure out how because I have no knowledge in js..

```
function(){
  var select = this.$input[0];
  $('#resetSmartSelect').on('click', function(){
    select.selectize.setValue([]);
  });
}
```

maybe it should be `smartSelect.setValue([])` instead but dont know how to implement it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution for this. If someone in the future faces a similar problem, just put this on top of your UI:

```
tags$head(
  tags$script(HTML('
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#idOfTheResetButton").on("click", function() {
            var smartSelect  = app.smartSelect.get("#idOfTheSmartSelect");
            for(let i = 0; i < smartSelect.$selectEl[0].length; i++) {
                smartSelect.$selectEl[0][i].selected = false;
            }
            smartSelect.setValue([]);
            });})
          '
          )))
```

probably not the best solution I guess. I just tried a few things out and this one works :)